# Creating a column in a dataframe based on substring of another column, scala

Tags: sql, scala, substring

I have a column in `dataframe(d1)`: `MODEL_SCORE`, which has value like `nulll7880`.
I want to create another `column MODEL_SCORE1` in `datframe` which is substring of `MODEL_SCORE`.

I am trying this. It's creating column, but not giving expected result:

```
val x=d1.withColumn("MODEL_SCORE1", substring(col("MODEL_SCORE"),0,4))

val y=d1.select(col("MODEL_SCORE"), substring(col("MODEL_SCORE"),0,4).as("MODEL_SCORE1"))
```

Answer (score 2):

One way for this is you can define a UDF that will split your column string value as per your need. A sample code be as follow,

`val df = sc.parallelize(List((1,"nulll7880"),(2,"null9000"))).toDF("id","col1")
df.show`

//output

`+---+---------+
| id|     col1|
+---+---------+
|  1|nulll7880|
|  2| null9000|
+---+---------+`

`def splitString:(String => String) = {str => str.slice(0,4)}
val splitStringUDF = org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf(splitString)
df.withColumn("col2",splitStringUDF(df("col1"))).show`

//output

`+---+---------+----+
| id|     col1|col2|
+---+---------+----+
|  1|nulll7880|null|
|  2| null9000|null|
+---+---------+----+`

Comment: Thanks, Can I do it without creating UDF?

Comment: You can also use df.withColumn("col2",substring(df("col1"),4,3)).show
Here 4 is the position in the string and 3 is the total length of the string from that position.